# Filter Array based on if contains php

Tags: php, arrays

My aim here is to remove the whole object from the array if "record_type" is null. I should then only be left with data that has a record_type set in the array.

I've looked into the array filter not sure how I target the data within the array "record_type".  My only other thought is to import to a database and then SQL query what I want then delete data I've had which is much more overkill.

```
<pre>


array:36 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "type" => "comment"
    "line_index" => 0
    "text_b64" => "OyBjUGFuZWwgZmlyc3Q6ODguMC4xMiAodXBkYXRlX3RpbWUpOjE2MTg1NDYxNDIgQ3BhbmVsOjpab25lRmlsZTo6VkVSU0lPTjoxLjMgaG9zdG5hbWU6cjExOC5sb24yLm15c2VjdXJlY2xvdWRob3N0LmNvbSBs ▶"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "line_index" => 1
    "text_b64" => "OyBab25lIGZpbGUgZm9yIG9ha3RyZWVkZW50YWxtb3J0aW1lci5jby51aw=="
    "type" => "comment"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "text_b64" => "JFRUTCAxNDQwMA=="
    "line_index" => 2
    "type" => "control"
  ]
  3 => array:6 [▼
    "line_index" => 3
    "dname_b64" => "b2FrdHJlZWRlbnRhbG1vcnRpbWVyLmNvLnVrLg=="
    "record_type" => "SOA"
    "ttl" => 30
    "type" => "record"
    "data_b64" => array:7 [▶]
  ]
  4 => array:6 [▼
    "dname_b64" => "b2FrdHJlZWRlbnRhbG1vcnRpbWVyLmNvLnVrLg=="
    "line_index" => 10
    "record_type" => "NS"
    "ttl" => 30
    "type" => "record"
    "data_b64" => array:1 [▶]
  ]
  5 => array:6 [▼
    "ttl" => 30
    "dname_b64" => "b2FrdHJlZWRlbnRhbG1vcnRpbWVyLmNvLnVrLg=="
    "line_index" => 11
    "record_type" => "NS"
    "data_b64" => array:1 [▶]
    "type" => "record"
  ]
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goal: only be left with data that has a 'record_type' set (not `null`) in the array

Solution: use `array_filter()` on your source array (`$arr`) and filter for records with `'record_type' != "NS"` (assuming "NS" is what you refer to as `null`, or not set).

```
<?php
$result = array_filter(
    $arr,
    function (array $record) {
        if (isset($record['record_type'])) {
            return $record['record_type'] != "NS";
        } return null;
    }
);
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/brWXg)

### EDIT

If you want to filter for only those records that are of a certain type, e.g. type 'record', following should help:

```
<?php
$result = array_filter(
    $arr,
    function (array $record) {
        if ($record['type'] == 'record') {
            return true;
        } return false;
    }
);
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/MB6Il)

Comment: Thanks, The aim is to basically remove any objects where isn't a record_type set which is normally when the type is "control" or "comment". I think that you've basically pointed me to what I can need will try it tonight and let you know and will mark as correct. Thank you for taking the time to view this.

Comment: I was able to filter exactly what I wantede using that method.
`$records = array_filter(
    $domainDNS,
    function (array $record) {
        if ($record['type'] == 'record' && $record['record_type'] !== 'SOA' && $record['record_type'] !== 'NS') {
            return true;
        } return false;
    }
);`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If your Goal is to filter array to remove any inner-array that hasn't a *record_type*, So use `array_filter` with a callback function `fn` to check that `record_type` exist with `isset` function.

```php
array_filter($arr, fn($el)=>isset($el["record_type"]));
```